# Need explanation on character types in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I went through the documentation on character types of PostgreSQL. But still I have some questions

"char" is fixed length i,e 1 
if so what is length of "char[]" because I am not able to change it in pgadmin I thought it is used for variable length character array. So, what is the actual default size?

What is use of character as compared to "char"[]? For now I assume character is used for fixed length character array for which we define size.

Why character[] is used?

What is difference between character varying and character varying[]?

Comment: `[]` denotes an **array**, not a single value: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/arrays.html

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In case you come from a C background, a character string type in PostgreSQL is *not* an array of characters.

For each type `foo` in PostgreSQL, there is a corresponding array type `foo[]` that denotes an array of values of type `foo`. Use array types only if you do not plan to manipulate them much inside the database; if you do, it is usually better to normalize the array into a separate table.

Leaving aside array types, there are different character types:

- `"char"` (the double quotes are required): a single character. Mostly used in catalog tables. Don't use this type unless you know what you are doing.
- `character(n)` or `char(n)`: fixed length characters string. No matter what you store there, it will always be padded with spaces on the right side. The behaviour, as dictated by the SQL standard, is sometimes surprising, so you rarely want this type.
- `text`: arbitrary-length character string. This is the type you want for characters strings unless you want the database to impose a length limit.
- `character varying(n)` or `varchar(n)`: this is the same as `text` with an additional length limit.

To round it off with an example:

```
CREATE TABLE strtest(
   id serial PRIMARY KEY,
   sc "char",
   c character(10),
   vc character varying(10),
   vca character varying(10)[]
);

INSERT INTO strtest (sc, c, vc, vca)
   VALUES (
      'x',
      'short',
      'short',
      ARRAY['short1', 'short2', 'short3']
   );

SELECT sc, c, vc, vca[2] FROM strtest;
 sc |     c      |  vc   |  vca
----+------------+-------+--------
 x  | short      | short | short2
(1 row)
```

Comment: Great demo, I'm from the traditional RDBMS side. Ran the queries you provided above, it seems this array [] feature can serve like a denormalized format encapsulates all tabular cells of a column into one. Reading [this](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/arrays.html) it says at the bottom `Arrays are not sets; searching for specific array elements can be a sign of database misdesign. Consider using a separate table with a row for each item that would be an array element. This will be easier to search, and is likely to scale better for a large number of elements.` Any benefit of array?

Comment: If you have a background in databases, you will know about normalization. Use arrays if the data stored in the array are atomic with respect to the database, that is, you don't plan to do database processing with individual elements. While it works quite well to use array elements in a `WHERE` condition, you are doing something wrong if you want to have foreign keys on array elements or want them in a join condition.

Comment: you are very knowledgeable, appreciate if a real-life example showing the benefit. For example, column `Salary` is `int[]`. We'll just keep appending to this array. To find out the pay at a certain time, we'll have to query this array `Salary[x]` corresponding to period `x`. This is simple and straightforward in traditional RDBMS. How does Array help in this scenario? Thank you very much in advanced.

Comment: I don't know how an array helps with this example. I'd model it differently. But it all depends on your queries: if they are simple and efficient, you are good.