# Why each data type has two choices in pgAdmin 4?

Tags: pgadmin-4

Using pgAdmin 4, defining data type for a table column discover each type has two choices, what's the difference?
for example `char` has two choices.

[image]

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/arrays.html

Comment: @drum what's the real benefits of encapsulating multiple cells into one? thanks

Comment: Denormalization. Rather than breaking up each element of the array into multiple rows, remove the need for redundant rows.

Comment: @drum thanks for the input. I'm from the traditional RDBMS. Denormalized typically helps reporting. In order to do so, for example we have `Salary` as `int[]`, will have to do `pay_period` as array as well, and so cascade to all related, then in turn the whole database is denormalized, could be fast for reporting but not good on update and storage, in another word, won't be relational. Any case study or real-life example will be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: This comes in handy when data gets large, say TB+, and reporting transitioning to ELT. Imagine this array having many values. It will create many records. Disk will explode with the amount of normalized data. Joins will become incredibly expensive. Queries will start running for 30 mins, 1 hour, etc. Having the db return a single row and do post-processing will save a lot of time and resources.

Answer (score 0):

Because Postgres does not work like programming data structures. It is not keeping them on memory but disk. So each data structure has a single and fixed length array value. See for more information: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42484838/13638824

---

Edit for your question (It was too long to be comment):

Writing data structures to a memory and disk is totally different. Memory is dynamic and writing to it is very cheap so it can handle changes in data very fast. But writing to disk is not cheap, when database systems decide to write a data they are trying to be efficient as possible. They are usually using fixed sized allocations in background to improve performance. When you define a `Text` dbms will not create a `string`. It will write it to disk as expandable data structure to ensure flexibility and performance. But if you use `char[]` the length will be predefined so it will be more performant.

**TL;DR;**

For memory data structures:
`char[] == string`.
But for DBMS `char[] == fixed size byte array` and `text == flexible size byte array`.

Comment: Thanks for the good link. All databases are supposed to be written into disk, it's not mentioned memory vs. disk in that thread. Would you elaborate?